# How to prevent HttpClient from generating new lines when sending request?

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm creating a messenger app, currently working on the client side, and I already have programmed most of the API (server side).

I am trying to send a POST request to the server, but it places `\r\n` after every element of the packet (eg:-, `content-type header = application/json\r\n`)

This means that when my server attempts to validate whether the incoming traffic is in JSON format, it throws it off.

I have used WireShark to see what the packets look like, here's a screenshot:

[image]

The code that I have used to send the request:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRequestAsync(string path, object data)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(Main.ServerAddress + ":" + Main.ServerPort.ToString() + path),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,

        };


        MessageBox.Show("Content: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));




        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        MessageBox.Show(request.ToString());
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        }

        return response;
    }
```

The object that is being serialised as json / sent to server:

```cs
public class UserCreds{
    public string username;
    public string password;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

Here's the server code:

```
@server.route("/1/signup", methods=["POST"]) # Sign up a user.
def sign_up_user():
    if request.is_json == False:
        return make_response(), 400

userJson = request.get_json()

uName = userJson['username']
pWord = userJson['password']

#try:
file = open(userCredsFile, 'r')
fileRaw = file.read()

creds = {}
if fileRaw != "":
    creds = json.loads(fileRaw)

if uName in creds:
    return create_status_response("User already exists.")

else:
    creds[uName] = pWord

file.close()

file = open(userCredsFile, 'w')

file.write(json.dumps(creds))

file.close();

return make_response(), 201

#except e:
#    return create_status_response("Something happened.")
```

Comment: That’s exactly how the HTTP specification wants it to be. How else would you separate the lines?

Comment: Are you sure the literal characters "\" "r" "\n" are sent? Or are those just the way your debugging tool displays an actual end of line (which is required by the HTTP specification)?

Comment: Can we see the code that validates the content type?

Comment: The code that validates the content type is on the server, and the server is using the Flask framework for python. It just checks if it is JSON by using: Flask.request.is_json.

I believe that it is reading \r\n as actual text, because it is of different formatting?

Comment: Can you post a pic of WireShark with the binary pane (lower) synced to the text pane?

Comment: I just had a look at other packets in wireshark through my network. Seems that all of them have the \r\n on the end. Well, it is returning 400 because it is a 'bad request', I am not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Why do you think this is causing the check to fail in the first place? In any case this is completely correct. Wireshark is showing literal forms of those characters since otherwise you wouldn’t know they’re there. It’s per HTTP specification and there’s nothing wrong with this. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: See above edit for server code.